# How to update a SQL Server table using the latest record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
 | number |         date           | 
 +--------+------------------------+
 | p1     |2014-08-23 23:45:49.9902|
 | p1     |2014-08-23 23:46:32.033 |
```

I have a table in SQL Server as above with thousands of records, I would like to be able to update the latest record

```
 update tableA  
 set number='p2'
 where date=????
```

Thanks in advance for the help

I used `GETDATE()` to save the records

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 update tableA  
 set number='p2'
 where date = (select max(date) from tableA)
```

Comment: What if there are multiple rows with `max(date)` ?

Answer (score 3):

If there can be multiple rows with the same Latest date value and you only want to update ONE row you can use the following

```
;WITH CTE AS
 (
   SELECT TOP 1 number
   FROM tableA  
   ORDER BY [Date] DESC
 )
UPDATE CTE
 SET number = 'p2'
```

Comment: Correct me if am wrong, am just curious if the records reach over million, will `ORDER BY` affect the performance of the server?